# Lumen: get URL parameter in a Blade view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, lumen

I'm trying to get a url parameter from a view file.

I have this url:

```
http://locahost:8000/example?a=10
```

and a *view* file named `example.blade.php`.

From the controller I can get the parameter `a` with `$request->input('a')`.

Is there a way to get such parameter from the view (without having to pass it from the controller to the view)?

Comment: You could access the `$_GET[]` array, but I wouldn't recommend doing that. You should pass it from the controller to the view, not sure why you woulnd't want to.

Comment: @TimLewis I would avoid to pass it from the controller because if I have a lot of parameters it could be annoying, and it should be more quick having a way to get it directly from the view.

Comment: I guess it can be tedious to define and pass a lot of variables from the controller to the view, but I would take tediousness over bad practices any day...

Comment: Think about the reason why you can't access $request directly in view, also why accessing $_GET,$_POST,$_REQUEST directly is bad practice

Comment: @mvladk true, actually. Frameworks remove potentially bad data from these variables.

Answer (score 158):

This works well:

```
{{ app('request')->input('a') }}
```

Where `a` is the url parameter.

See more here: http://blog.netgloo.com/2015/07/17/lumen-getting-current-url-parameter-within-a-blade-view/

Comment: this will return all params `app('request')->request->all()`

Comment: what would be the way if my URL is like http://locahost:8000/example/10  and I wanna get the value 10. @Andrea

Comment: @SajeebAhamed Better you ask this as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 72):

The shortest way i have used

```
{{ Request::get('a') }}
```

Comment: Where is this documented?

Answer (score 53):

Given your URL:

```
http://locahost:8000/example?a=10
```

The best way that I have found to get the value for 'a' and display it on the page is to use the following:

```
{{ request()->get('a') }}
```

However, if you want to use it within an if statement, you could use:

```
@if( request()->get('a') )
    <script>console.log('hello')</script>
@endif
```

Answer (score 31):

More simple in Laravel 5.7 and 5.8

```
{{ Request()->parameter }}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Laravel 5.8

```
{{ request()->a }}
```

Answer (score 11):

This works fine for me:

```
{{ app('request')->input('a') }}
```

Ex: to get pagination param on blade view:

```
{{ app('request')->input('page') }}
```

Answer (score 9):

As per official **5.8** docs:

> The request() function returns the current request instance or obtains an input item:

```
$request = request();

$value = request('key', $default);
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-request)

Answer (score 7):

You can publicly expose `Input` facade via an alias in `config/app.php`:

```
'aliases' => [
    ...

    'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
]
```

And access url `$_GET` parameter values using the facade directly inside Blade view/template:

```
{{ Input::get('a') }}
```

Comment: Lumen has /config folder?

Answer (score 7):

All the answers above are correct, but there's a quickier way to do this.

```
{{request("a")}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Laravel 5.6:

```
{{ Request::query('parameter') }}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

As per [official documentation **8.x**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request)

We use the helper `request`

> The request function returns the current request instance or obtains
> an input field's value from the current request:

```
$request = request();

$value = request('key', $default);
```

> the value of request is an array you can simply retrieve your input using the input key as follow

```
$id = request()->id; //for http://locahost:8000/example?id=10
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use route and pass paramater use this code in your blade file

```
{{dd(request()->route()->parameters)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to get filtered data with pagination

```
$queryvariable->appends($data)->links('link of new page');
```

note there

```
$data = $request->all();
```