# Is there a way to check for a specific parameter in a url with php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am using a package called chatter and managed to include it in my own post.
Now I have a table called games, and every time I create a new game, I also add a chatter discussion. That works.

So, on the single game page, I load the details of the game and the chatter discussions as an iframe. Meaning that now I have an HTML inside an HTML.
Users are now able to use chatter discussions.

The controller looks pretty much like this:

```
public function show(Game $game)
{
    // We know this is a game
    // Get the category first
    $category = DB::table('chatter_categories')->whereName('Game')->first();

    // Get the discussion
    // A discussion has many post(s)
    $discussion = DB::table('chatter_discussion')->whereChatterCategoryId($category->id)->first();
                                             //dd($chatter_post);
    return view('games.games', ['game' => $game, 'discussion' => $discussion, 'category' => $category]);
}
```

Now, in my games.blade I have the following:

```
<article id="discussion">
    <iframe id="myiframe" src="/forums/discussion/{{ $category->slug }}/{{ $discussion->slug }}" style="height: 800px; width: 100%;" frameborder="0" />
</article>
```

Chatter default page comes with a header and looks like in the image below:

[image]

If I view a game that I create, I also see the chatter discussions for that games as expected:

[image]

Question: How can I remove the header section of the chatter discussion only on the games page?

If I simply target the header id directly

```
div#chatter_header{ 
    display: none;
}
```

It will remove the heading, but that will also go away if I visit chatter original front end view.

This is when I thought of checking the current page URL and the styling accordingly, but this does not work.

My route for the games look like this:

```
Route::resource('games', 'GameController');
```

Comment: What's your route definition?

Comment: Route definition would help more.

Comment: Try this

{{ Request::segment(1) }}   // 1 is the URL parameter position. You can change this 2 or whatever.

Comment: Your question seems wrong, since you're asking for a parameter, but you actually mean a path segment (judging by the url you provided).

Answer (score 3):

If you use Laravel, you can do this with URL query parameters:

```
if ($request->has('forums')) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input

In your template, you can use:

```
@if(app('request')->input('forums'))
   <span>Do stuff</span>
@endif
```

See: [Lumen: get URL parameter in a Blade view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324801/lumen-get-url-parameter-in-a-blade-view)

Comment: This will check if query string parameter has `forums`.

Comment: @SougataBose You are right. I was assuming the question refers to query string parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can try -

```
$parse = parse_url('http://domain.local/forums/discussion/game/sidney-game', PHP_URL_PATH);

if (strpos($parse, '/forums/') === 0) {
  // do what needed
}
```

It will check if the path starts with `forums`.

Comment: I think you're missing the 2nd parameter in `parse_url`

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parsedURL = parse_url($actual_link);
parse_str($parsedURL['forums'], $parts);
echo $query['forums'];
```