# @if (request::is("/")) doesnt work laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

i am making a basic website and i am trying to make function that will show the content of the file "showcase" in "inc" folder only on a homepage, the page seems to work fine without it....

```html
<body>
    @include("inc.navbar")
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @yield("content")

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @include("inc.sidebar")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[image]

but when i add a function:

```html
<body>
    @include("inc.navbar")
    <div class="container">
        @if (request::is("/"))
        @include('inc.showcase')
        @endif
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @yield("content")

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                @include("inc.sidebar")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

it shows this error:
[image]

I suspect it must be some path problem, but i havent found any issue with path name or anything... any ideas? Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: May be this link help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324801/lumen-get-url-parameter-in-a-blade-view.

Comment: try `@if (Request::is("/"))` instead of `@if (request::is("/"))`.

Comment: ab.in Yeah this worked! thank you for your advice. And sorry for wasting your time, i should have seen that.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Request::is`, Request is a class.

Comment: thats what i did here no? can you please elaborate? Possible include a snippet, i am not sure i am following completely tbh....

Comment: Changing first letter to Capital actually worked! Thanks a lot, i feel stupid now, but lesson learned, thank you for your input.