# How do I get url parameter in Blade template (Laravel v8)

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

As the title suggests, I am resurrecting an old Laravel project (from v5) and upgrading to v8.

In my blade template I referred to `$request->q` which would get the `q=somevalue` part of my url, in laravel 8 however this doesn't work.

I have tried a number of methods found in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324801/lumen-get-url-parameter-in-a-blade-view) but none of them work.

Comment: Are you passing `$request` variable to the blade ?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be passing through this variable no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `request()` helper function with one of these

```
request('q')
```

```
request()->get('q')
```

```
request()->query('q')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too but Still, it will works, when it in this way

### Controller

- in here this should have `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

`public function func1(Request $request){`
 `$aid=$request->id;`
`}`

### Route

```
Route::get('/url_name/{id}',[
    'as'=>'url_name',
    'uses'=>'ControllerName@func1'
]);
```

### Blade

```
<form id="form_1" action="{{'/url_name',$id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

OR

You can try with,
`$request['q'];`